# C++ Combining Static and Dynamic Polymorphism to Create "Hyper Polymorphism"?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

By mixing both static and dynamic polymorphism (templates and inheritance) I have come across a strange technique that functions similarly to regular static polymorphism in C++, except the members of the child class are still visible after creating the new object.

***Consider the following example:***

---

**Base.h:**

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}

    virtual void say_hello() {
        std::cout << "Hello from Base!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

---

**Class1.h:**

```
#include "Base.h"
#include <iostream>

class Class1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void say_hello() {
        std::cout << "Hello from Class1!" << std::endl;
    }

    int x = 1;
};
```

---

**Class2.h:**

```
#include "Base.h"
#include <iostream>

class Class2 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void say_hello() {
        std::cout << "Hello from Class2!" << std::endl;
    }

    int y = 2;
};
```

---

***This is where things get interesting...***

**ClassX.h**

```
template <class T>
class ClassX : public T {
public:
    int z = 3;
};
```

---

By implementing classX in such a way that it can dynamically inherit from anything it allows some strange things to occur.  See the example below showing it in use.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Base.h"
#include "Class1.h"
#include "Class2.h"
#include "ClassX.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Base* b = new Base;
    b->say_hello();

    // Regular polymorphism in action
    Base* c1 = new Class1;
    c1->say_hello();         // Aware that this is Class1
    //cout << c1->x << endl; // Doesn't work! Not visible from here

    Base* c2 = new Class2;
    c2->say_hello();         // Aware that this is Class2
    //cout << c2->y << endl; // Doesn't work! Not visible from here

    // Hyper polymorphism!? Not sure what to call this.
    ClassX<Class1> cx1;
    cx1.say_hello();       // Aware that this is Class1
    cout << cx1.x << endl; // The member variable is visible!
    cout << cx1.z << endl; // Also available :)

    ClassX<Class2> cx2;
    cx2.say_hello();       // Aware that this is Class2
    cout << cx2.y << endl; // The member variable is visible!
    cout << cx2.z << endl; // Also available :)

    // ALWAYS delete objects created with "new" or shame on yew.
    delete b;
    delete c1;
    delete c2;
}
```

---

What I'm wondering is why have I never seen this technique before?  I've never once seen anyone try to inherit from an unknown class using templates like this:

```
template <class T>
class Name : public T {
    // Implementation
};
```

***Is there a name to this technique, and what are it's uses?***

I just gave it a try because knowing the rules of C++ I didn't see a reason why it wouldn't work.  Since I can't seem to find a name for it anywhere I'm going to call this technique "Hyper Polymorphism" :)

Comment: What is new here? Inheriting a T? That is quite silly imho.

Comment: I guess it's not really new, it just seems to be incredibly uncommon

Comment: For a very good reason.

Comment: What do you solve by adding CRTP?  You can get everything you you have in your code, besides `z`, without it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15447f04bafae7de

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe What is that reason? Part of why I asked this question is because I wanted to know why it isn't used.  I assumed it wasn't good practice but I can't think of any specific reasons why.

Comment: Read "Modern C++ Design". The book is a bit old (over 17 years), but still explains spectacularly some advanced techniques where inheriting from the template parameter is key.

Comment: Apart from the pattern Nathan mentioned the entire premise is kinda silly.

Comment: @NathanOliver I found a situation where I essentially needed to add a `z` and still have all of the functionality of the other classes.  This example is simplified from how I was really intending on using it.

Comment: I dont really understand the hype in your polymorphism. Your `ClassX<Class2>` is exactly the same as if you had  written `class ClassX : public Class2 {}`. There may be some applications of that technique, but for itself imho it isnt that shocking

Comment: The template part looks like a *mixin*. You'd typically have some functions to enhance the behaviour of `T` in there.

Comment: @tobi303, imagine there are hundreds of `Class1, Class2, Class3`... and so on. I don't want to have to write a separate `ClassX` that inherits from each individual one. I only need to define a single `ClassX`.

Comment: " except the members of the child class are still visible after creating the new object." could you expand a bit on this part? It isnt clear to me at all what you mean with that, or how this differs from plain normal inheritance

Comment: @tobi303, with normal polymorphism, when you create an instance of the child class through the base class the members that are not part of the base class itself are not visible so you can't access them. Look at the comments in the code that say "Not visible from here", they somewhat help clear it up.

Comment: O wait, this isn't CRTP.  In CRTP the base class is templated on the derived class.  This is just plain inheritance.  Not really static polymorphism.

Comment: The use of templates is where the static polymorphism comes in.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but thats not different with that technique as compared to normal inheritance. If you create an instance via `Class2* x = new ClassX<Class2>();` you need to cast it to a `ClassX` before you can use it as a `ClassX`, just as with normal inheritance.

Comment: @Quentin is right. Here `Base* c1 = new Class1;`, c1 is `Base`. `say_hello` inherits from the behaviour of Class1, but does not inherits the new class member `x`. It's logical.

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne, `x` is a member of `Class1`, not `ClassX`

Comment: @tjwrona1992 -- Hopefully you don't write base classes without a virtual destructor.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 thats what Im saying, `x` is a new member in `Class1`, thus not available in `Base`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, You're right! My mistake!

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne, `x` is visible when accessed through `ClassX` though even though it is not a member of `ClassX` that's why this is interesting.  It lets you extend the functionality of any number of classes by implementing only one new generic class.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 because `ClassX` inherits from `T`, which in this case, is `Class1`. And `Class1` can have access to `Class1::x`.

Comment: Seems me a decorator pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Static_Decorator_.28Mixin_Inheritance.29

Comment: What is the actual *question* here?  SO is not a good place to paste "here's a cool technique I just discovered, whad'ya think?"

Comment: Not sure what's so special here. `cx1` and `cx2` aren't using any polymorphism at all.

Comment: @MarkRansom, Templates are just another form of polymorphism :)

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, this isn't some new special technique you just invented. *Of course* if you have an object of type `X` you can access all the public members, what's so surprising about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the comments it looks like this technique is actually considered a "[decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Static_Decorator_.28Mixin_Inheritance.29)".

It can be used when you need to extend the functionality of multiple existing classes (for example adding a member variable `z`) when you can't modify the classes directly.

It's more flexible than regular inheritance because you can extend the functionality of many classes by only writing one new class.

Not exactly the same as "hyper polymorphism", but hey, maybe that will be a thing some day. ;)

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: sorry misunderstood an important part of OPs code. Shame on me. Removed the wrong part of my answer. However, the following still holds...

Imho your comparison isnt fair

```
Base* c2 = new Class2;
//cout << c2->y << endl; // Doesn't work! Not visible from here

ClassX<Class1> cx1;
cout << cx1.x << endl; // The member variable is visible!
```

These are two completely different cases. A fair comparison would be

```
Base* c2 = new Class2;
//cout << c2->y << endl; // Doesn't work! Not visible from here
```

vs

```
Base* cx1 = new ClassX<Class1>();
//cout << cx1->x << endl; // Wont work as well !!!
```

(see [here](http://ideone.com/Xwc304) for an example) or

```
Class2 c2;
cout << c2.y << endl; // Works of course
```

vs

```
ClassX<Class1> cx1;
cout << cx1.x << endl; // Works of course as well !!!
```

That said, this technique might have its applications. For example the case you mentioned in a comment, when you need to add the same functionality to many differnt base classes.

> Is there a name to this technique, and what are it's uses?

Afaik there isnt a name for this. The uses are, as others have mentioned in comments, to decorate many different classes with the same functionality.

I have to admit that only after @Amadeus pointed out that half of my answer was wrong, I fully understood the approach in OPs code. Imho it is quite some effort (twice inheriting plus a template) for not too much gain, and maybe thats the reason why it isnt a well known and commonly applied technique. Though it might be useful in some special cases.

Comment: You are right that it is quite a bit of effort to write up a full working example, but I actually discovered it because I already had a base class and some child classes that I didn't write myself (and couldn't modify) and I needed to "decorate" the child classes with additional functionality.  With that structure in place it was just a matter of writing the "decorator" class that inherits from `T` which is not much work at all. :)

Comment: Also with `Class1* cx1 = new ClassX<Class1>();` The member variable `x` would be visible.  I think you may have intended to say `Base* cx1 = new ClassX<Class1>();`

Comment: @tjwrona1992 yes, I get your point. I have to takes some time to play a bit with it. I was thinking to delete the answer until fixed, but I will just leave it as is until I have time to improve it